# During Incoming Call If I used Thread then App Crash using Plivo SDK and get Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler, plivo, android-thread

I am using Service for checking the status of Plivo Login and Handler can perform this action on Service Class and I called service from another Activity. If Incoming call is coming then Immediately App crash. And I get this Error.

**“A/libc: ../src/pj/os_core_unix.c:692:  pj_thread_this: assertion "!"Calling pjlib from unknown/external thread. You must " "register external threads with pj_thread_register() " "before calling any pjlib functions."" failed**”

“**A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9296 (MyService)**”

Comment: Have you tried doing exactly what it says?  Call pj_thread_register to register the thread before calling any other pjlib functions.

Comment: now I cant. Pjlib Library called from jar file. There is no method to directly register my current thread to that pj_thread.

Comment: Then look for some initialization function you missed in the library. Otherwise the jar has a bug and you'll need to fix it there

Comment: right. jar library must have the method which is register my current thread. and now that is not implemented on Jar file. Thanks @GabeSechan

Comment: if possible. any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

This problem might occur when you have initialised the endpoint in the main activity and pass it's reference to the service. You could try initialising the endpoint and callbacks (like onIncomingCall, onLogin) in the service and when the callback occurs, invoke the main activity from a runnable. Like this -

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        // call main activity or any other class function here..
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

You can raise a support ticket [here](https://support.plivo.com/) for further assistance.